# generic error occurred in gdi+ vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

hope fully its not repeated question coz i do too much search not find any answer.
my code for saving image to database is

```
Private Function ConvertImageToRGBFormat(ByVal imgName As String) As Image
    Dim img As Image
    img = New Bitmap(imgName)
    If Not img.PixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb Then
        Dim temp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(temp)
        g.DrawImage(img, New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        g.Dispose()
        Return temp
    End If
    Return img
End Function
Private Sub btnTravel_Info_Room_Image_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTravel_Info_Room_Image.Click
    Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog
    If dlg.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim bt As Byte()
        Dim myImage As Image
        myImage = ConvertImageToRGBFormat(dlg.FileName)
        Using stream = New MemoryStream()
            myImage.Save(stream, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            bt = stream.ToArray()
            myImage = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream, True))
        End Using
        picTravel_Info_Hotel.Tag = bt
        picTravel_Info_Hotel.BackgroundImage = myImage
    End If
End Sub
```

and code for getting image from database to picturebox is, and here i am getting error

```
Dim BArray As Byte() = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Room_Image"), Byte())
Using MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream(BArray)
    picTravel_Info_Hotel.Tag = BArray
    MS.Position = 0
    picTravel_Info_Hotel.BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(MS, True))
    MS.Dispose()
End Using
```

and i am getting "**generic error occurred in gdi+**" error on some of our pc's not on every one when i am getting image from database.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: **where** do you get the error?

Comment: here i am getting error when getting data back from database          Dim BArray As Byte() = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Room_Image"), Byte())
                        Using MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream(BArray)
                            picTravel_Info_Hotel.Tag = BArray
                            MS.Position = 0
                            picTravel_Info_Hotel.BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(MS, True))
                            MS.Dispose()
                        End Using

Answer (score 3):

There are several bugs in this code that causes that exception.  The missing Dispose() call for the *img* object inside your If() statement is a trouble maker.  It will leave the file locked for an unpredictable amount of time, trying to overwrite the file will cause this exception.

But the primary bug is:

```
Using MS As New System.IO.MemoryStream(BArray)
```

The *Using* statement is incorrect, it makes the stream in-accessible.  The Image class can access the stream *after* you've called the FromStream() method.  In typical .NET lazy fashion, only executing code when required.  This is not consistently done, only some kind of images will be accessed lazily.  When it does, it suffers a heart attack when it discovers that the stream is no longer usable and reports it with a GenericException.  You must keep the stream usable until the image can no longer be used.  Note that you got this wrong in more than one place.  Remove *Using* to fix, don't bother disposing it.

Comment: That problem with disposing the stream made some of my worst nightmares a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html

Could lack of permissions when writing the temporary file to disk be the problem? I see ConvertImageToRGBFormat, does this save the image to disk, in order for the conversion to be done? Make sure write permissions are available for the folder containing the images before saving to DB.

Comment: dear i am not saving image to any folder or file. so no issue about permissions converting just convert image to RGBformat

Comment: Try encapsulating Image.FromStream(stream, True), into a using block as well. It could be related to the issue that you have to keep the stream open for the lifetime of the image. See documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx

Comment: dear if you will check my code which is getting data from database is already in using statement ;)